# Issue with cursor position in timeline on drag and drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, timeline.js

Dragging an item results in the cursor being out of place, as can be seen from the screenshots. The cursor isn’t where the item is, and has an offset. This is the case even with both start and end times present. Closing the window on the left doesn’t help either.

[image]
[image: item disappears after dragging]
item disappears after dragging.

Comment: Are you using vis.js or timeline.js? If it's vis.js, please remove the `timeline.js` tag and add the `vis.js-timeline` tag so that the question is not that confusing. Best regards